# Handling multi line and carriage return in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a csv file that has text qualifiers "" for the text fields. The file also contains multiple lines with carriage returns in some fields. I have looked at other stackoverflow posts and couldn't find one that can help me with the issue that I am facing. The data looks like this

file here: dropbox.com/sh/nqmhdckae628ntc/AAAK7lU6wJcWkPTv5y3ZWyhRa?dl=0

```
"Project ID","Initiative Name",Status,Type,Submitter,"Submitted Date",CEP,Maverick,Toolbox,"External Labour",M&A,"Embedded in Plan","Start Date","End Date",Category,"TS Prime","VP Reporting Group","Benefiting BU","Vendor Name","TS Finance Prime","TS Director Prime","TS VP Prime","Finance Approved","Delivery Model",Baseline,"WLS Allocation","WLN Allocation"
1234,"xyz",Incremental,"Budget Impacting Savings","Some VP","2019-10-31 14:54:14.670",FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,"Embedded in plan",2019-09-09,2020-09-08,"Information Technology","some vp",Procurement,"some info some info
some info
some info
some info","something","some vp","some vp","another vp",Yes,"whatever",1.68,1,1
123,"abc",Incremental,"Non-Budget Impact Savings","some vp","2020-01-22 15:48:57.323",FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,,2020-01-14,2020-05-31,"Information Technology","some vp",Procurement,"some info
some info
some info",something,"some vp","some vp","some vp",,"whatever",2,0,10
```

There are two records here "Project ID" 1234 and 123. When I read this file into pandas it does the job:

```
df_test= pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=",",quotechar='"')
```

the output of the first row looks like this:

```
Project ID                                                         1234
Initiative Name                                                     xyz
Status                                                      Incremental
Type                                           Budget Impacting Savings
Submitter                                                       Some VP
Submitted Date                                  2019-10-31 14:54:14.670
CEP                                                               False
Maverick                                                          False
Toolbox                                                           False
External Labour                                                   False
M&A                                                               False
Embedded in Plan                                       Embedded in plan
Start Date                                                   2019-09-09
End Date                                                     2020-09-08
Category                                         Information Technology
TS Prime                                                        some vp
VP Reporting Group                                          Procurement
Benefiting BU         some info some info\r\nsome info\r\nsome info\...
Vendor Name                                                   something
TS Finance Prime                                                some vp
TS Director Prime                                               some vp
TS VP Prime                                                  another vp
Finance Approved                                                    Yes
Delivery Model                                                 whatever
Baseline                                                           1.68
WLS Allocation                                                        1
WLN Allocation                                                        1
Name: 0, dtype: objectenter code here
```

We can see the /r/n in the output column Benefiting BU . I want to read the file in spark using pyspark. The files that we are dealing with are on an average 4.5GB. Pandas cannot handle such large files so using spark to load and process the files. I tried to read the file in pyspark using the "option("multiLine","true")" but it does not seem to work. It only gives me a count of one record and that is the first one. It does not recognize the second row.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("quote",'"').option("escape","/"").option("multiLine","true").csv("data.csv")
df.show()


  +----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|Project ID|Initiative Name|     Status|                Type|Submitter|      Submitted Date|  CEP|Maverick|Toolbox|External Labour|  M&A|Embedded in Plan|Start Date|  End Date|            Category|TS Prime|VP Reporting Group|       Benefiting BU|Vendor Name|TS Finance Prime|TS Director Prime|TS VP Prime|Finance Approved|Delivery Model|Baseline|WLS Allocation|WLN Allocation|
+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|      1234|            xyz|Incremental|Budget Impacting ...|  Some VP|2019-10-31 14:54:...|false|   false|  false|          false|false|Embedded in plan|2019-09-09|2020-09-08|Information Techn...| some vp|       Procurement|some info some in...|  something|         some vp|          some vp| another vp|             Yes|      whatever|    1.68|             1|         1
123|
+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------+--------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------+------------------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

Notice how its taking the first element from the second row but not the entire row and treats it as part of the first row. When I do a df.count() it gives me this just 1 when it should give me 2 as I have 2 records. If I read the csv without the multiLine option it recognizes each new line as a row which is fair as spark is built that way but that is not what I want.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Will really appreciate the help.I dont know if I can upload the test file that I showed you here if anyone wants to recreate the issue.

Comment: give your data.csv sample.

Comment: @Lamanus how can I upload here?

Comment: copy and paste it in your question.

Comment: @Lamanus its there in my question. Its the first code block. Thats how the data in the file looks like.

Comment: @Lamanus did a small edit on the data pasted here. It should be now the same data that I am looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I didn't specify the `quote` and `escape` but it works.

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("multiline","true").csv("test.csv")
df.count()

2
```

And

```
df.show(10, False)

+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|Project ID|Initiative Name|Status     |Type                     |Submitter|Submitted Date         |CEP  |Maverick|Toolbox|External Labour|M&A  |Embedded in Plan|Start Date|End Date  |Category              |TS Prime|VP Reporting Group|Benefiting BU                                    |Vendor Name|TS Finance Prime|TS Director Prime|TS VP Prime|Finance Approved|Delivery Model|Baseline|WLS Allocation|WLN Allocation|
+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|1234      |xyz            |Incremental|Budget Impacting Savings |Some VP  |2019-10-31 14:54:14.670|false|false   |false  |false          |false|Embedded in plan|2019-09-09|2020-09-08|Information Technology|some vp |Procurement       |some info some info
some info
some info
some info|something  |some vp         |some vp          |another vp |Yes             |whatever      |1.68    |1             |1             |
|123       |abc            |Incremental|Non-Budget Impact Savings|some vp  |2020-01-22 15:48:57.323|false|false   |false  |false          |false|null            |2020-01-14|2020-05-31|Information Technology|some vp |Procurement       |some info
some info
some info                    |something  |some vp         |some vp          |some vp    |null            |whatever      |2.0     |0             |10            |
+----------+---------------+-----------+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+-----+--------+-------+---------------+-----+----------------+----------+----------+----------------------+--------+------------------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

where the table is broken but you will see that there are two rows.

Comment: I still did not solve my issue. I am sharing the file with you via dropbox. The link is here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nqmhdckae628ntc/AAAK7lU6wJcWkPTv5y3ZWyhRa?dl=0 Maybe the way you copied it from the question might not have created the issue.

Comment: Are you using the Windows OS? I have tested on the Linux docker image but Windows fails as you did. hm...

Comment: Yes on windows 10 and spark version 3.0.0

Comment: :( Many tries and searches but couldn't found the answer, sorry. This happen only when the OS is Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. I searched high and low for this issue and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: I am going to accept your answer since I tried this on a VM running linux and it works. Thanks a lot for your help.